# SpaceVim undefined symbol: PyUnicode_FromFormat

Tags: python, linux, vim, spacevim

I am trying to use SpaceVim as my IDE. I install SpaceVim with

`curl -sLf https://spacevim.org/install.sh | bash`

Then I use

`vim test.py`

to make sure it works. Everything is OK when I first use command vim after it installed

However,when I use `vim` second time, it starts to install some plugins. After everything done, I encounter error every time I open a file and edit my file with `i o a`, They are

```
Error detected while processing /home/luo3300612/.cache/vimf
iles/repos/github.com/lilydjwg/fcitx.vim/plugin/fcitx.vim:
line   54:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing /home/luo3300612/.cache/vimf
iles/repos/github.com/lilydjwg/fcitx.vim/plugin/fcitx.vim:
line   54:
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing /home/luo3300612/.cache/vimf
iles/repos/github.com/lilydjwg/fcitx.vim/plugin/fcitx.vim:
line   54:
  File "/home/luo3300612/.cache/vimfiles/repos/github.com/li
lydjwg/fcitx.vim/plugin/fcitx.py", line 5, in <module>
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing /home/luo3300612/.cache/vimf
iles/repos/github.com/lilydjwg/fcitx.vim/plugin/fcitx.vim:
line   54:
    import socket
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing /home/luo3300612/.cache/vimf
iles/repos/github.com/lilydjwg/fcitx.vim/plugin/fcitx.vim:
line   54:
  File "/home/luo3300612/app/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/socket.
py", line 49, in <module>
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing /home/luo3300612/.cache/vimf
iles/repos/github.com/lilydjwg/fcitx.vim/plugin/fcitx.vim:
line   54:
    import _socket
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing /home/luo3300612/.cache/vimf
iles/repos/github.com/lilydjwg/fcitx.vim/plugin/fcitx.vim:
line   54:
ImportError: /home/luo3300612/app/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/li
b-dynload/_socket.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined
 symbol: PyUnicode_FromFormat
```

I find that there is a [issue](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/2840) on github. It says that this problem may appear when you use miniconda or anaconda. Then I uninstall my miniconda. The Error is gone.

But I can't use python without conda, so I wish anyone can help me to solve this problem!!!!

Comment: Try set 'pythonthreedll' option at the start of vimrc, and hope Vim can pick up the right Python.

Answer (score 0):

this is an issue of `lilydjwg/fcitx.vim`, this plugin should provides option to configuration python evn.

Comment: You spelled my name wrongly. The Python env has nothing to do with fcitx.vim; fcitx.vim uses whatever Python that is configured for Vim.

Comment: @lilydjwg Oh, sorry